# How to overlay Text Strip above Image in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to overlay a text strip above image view in react native. The ones you see on offers card. Attaching a screenshot below:

[image]

So far I've only managed something like this:
[image]

But this is very trivial. The right edge of the rectangle has to be slanted as well!

Is there any library/component that could do it ? I've searched all over but couldn't find one.
Would really appreciate any sort of help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think that's a CSS question.

Comment: No actually I'm trying to do it in my React Native app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with react-native but as far as I read you can provide styles as an object with any css property in camelCase notation: You can use clip-path to cut away the slanted part.

```
// regular css
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 96% 100%, 100% 0);
```

in react-native

```
const styles = {
  theStrip: {
    clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 96% 100%, 100% 0)',
  }
}
<div styles={styles.theStrip} />
```

[Further Reading](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-styled-components-with-react-native/)

Comment: Could you share the React Native equivalent for this.